# I'm using Gradio for making UI for my model

Tags: python, user-interface, recurrent-neural-network, gradio

```
def detect(audio):
    chime_threshold = 0.5
    prediction = detect_triggerword(audio)
    chime_on_activate(your_filename, prediction, chime_threshold)
    return IPython.display.Audio("./chime_output.wav")

detect=gr.Interface(fn=detect, inputs='audio', outputs='audio')
detect.launch()
```

[image: As you can see I'm able to add the audio file as input which is in WAV format but when I try to submit the file it shows me an error.]

[image: it is the error it shows]

Comment: As the error says, `gr.Interface` expects a file name.  You are passing an `IPython.display.Audio` object.  You should return `"../chime_output.wav"`, if that's what you want.